# App Crashes instantly after asking for location permission

Tags: java, android, location, crash

I have looked for question similar to this and all of them did not include the catlog so nobody could really help them. I have made sure to include it here so I hope you can help! Basically as soon as I Open the app it prompts me with a  location permission saying will I allow it. As soon as i hit yes, the app crashes!

```
package com.worden.jason.sample;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements LocationListener {
    LocationManager locationManager;
    public static final int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION = 99;
    String provider;
    public void Analysis(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Analysis.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }

    public void Tips(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Tips.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }

    public boolean checkLocationPermission() {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            // Should we show an explanation?
            if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)) {

                // Show an explanation to the user *asynchronously* -- don't block
                // this thread waiting for the user's response! After the user
                // sees the explanation, try again to request the permission.
                new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                        .setTitle(R.string.TileLocation)
                        .setMessage(R.string.TextLocation)
                        .setPositiveButton(R.string.Positive, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                                //Prompt the user once explanation has been shown
                                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,
                                        new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                                        MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION);
                            }
                        })
                        .create()
                        .show();
            } else {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                        new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                        MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION);
            }
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                           @NonNull String permissions[], @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION: {
                // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
                if (grantResults.length > 0
                        && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                    // location-related task you need to do.

                    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                            == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {


                        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 400, 1, this);
                    }

                } else {

                    // permission denied, boo! Disable the
                }
                return;
            }

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        if (checkLocationPermission()) {
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                    == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                //Request location updates:
                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 400, 1, this);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[log for crash](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GO3hl.png)

EDIT

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements LocationListener {
    LocationManager locationManager;
    public static final int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION = 99;
    **String GPS_PROVIDER;**
    public void Analysis(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Analysis.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }

    public void Tips(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Tips.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }
    **@Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);**
    }

    public boolean checkLocationPermission() {

        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            // Should we show an explanation?
            if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)) {

                // Show an explanation to the user *asynchronously* -- don't block
                // this thread waiting for the user's response! After the user
                // sees the explanation, try again to request the permission.
                new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                        .setTitle(R.string.TileLocation)
                        .setMessage(R.string.TextLocation)
                        .setPositiveButton(R.string.Positive, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                                //Prompt the user once explanation has been shown
                                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,
                                        new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                                        MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION);
                            }
                        })
                        .create()
                        .show();


            } else {

                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                        new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                        MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION);
            }
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                           @NonNull String permissions[], @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION: {
                // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
                if (grantResults.length > 0
                        && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {


                    // location-related task you need to do.

                    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                            == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {


                        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(GPS_PROVIDER, 400, 1, this);
                    }

                } else {

                    // permission denied, boo! Disable the


                }
                return;
            }

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

    }
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        if (checkLocationPermission()) {
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                    == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                //Request location updates:
                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(GPS_PROVIDER, 400, 1, this);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Two problems here:

1. You do not initialize the `locationManager` field. Your call to `locationManager.requestLocationUpdates` results in a `NullPointerException`.
2. You do not initialize the `provider` field. Your call to `locationManager.requestLocationUpdates` does not like this.

To fix the first problem, add this override:

```
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
}
```

To fix the second problem, throw out your `provider` field and use `LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER` (or one of the other providers defined in `LocationManager`) instead. Or initialize the `provider` field.

---

Setting breakpoints and running the program under a debugger is a good way to find such problems. Another approach is to look at logs – I'll bet there's a relevant stack trace in there somewhere.

---

Also ensure that your manifest mentions the requisite permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

Comment: Ok so i have tried implementing both of these things and it seems the error still occurs. My manifest already had access fine location and I am having a hard time following the logs as i am relatively new to android studio. If you would like the new code, which isn't very different from the original, just let me know. Thanks!

Comment: Works for me. Please update the post with your changes, and I'll have a look-see.

Comment: Your error log shows that the `locationManager` field is `null`. Since your code works just fine for me, I don't see what the problem is. You can work around the problem by deleting the field and instead creating a local variable in the two places you use the location manager.

Comment: could it be the device im using? Im not using an emulator. Also if it helps, the app does not crash when i deny permission

Comment: I don't think it's your device. If you can provide a [complete, minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that exhibits your problem I'll have another look.